# GraalVM can't find Mybatis LoggerFactory Constructor

Tags: java, mybatis

Currently, I am trying to use Spring Boot 3 with GraalVM native image with JDK 19.
GraalVM version is ce-java19-22.3

After i create native image successfully, run executable  file  ./target/demo_boot3.
Then, i got following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(MapperScannerConfigurer.java:363) ~[demo_boot3:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:745) ~[demo_boot3:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:565) ~[demo_boot3:6.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[demo_boot3:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[demo_boot3:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[demo_boot3:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[demo_boot3:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[demo_boot3:3.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[demo_boot3:3.0.0]
        at com.example.demo.boot3.DemoBoot3Application.main(DemoBoot3Application.java:45) ~[demo_boot3:na]
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogException: Error creating logger for logger org.mybatis.spring.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:54) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:47) ~[na:na]
        at org.mybatis.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:32) ~[na:na]
        at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner.<clinit>(ClassPathMapperScanner.java:60) ~[na:na]
        ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:52) ~[na:na]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Second step, then i try to init LogFactory manually by using static method, as following:

```
try {
   LogFactory.useSlf4jLogging();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
   LogFactory.useCommonsLogging();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
   LogFactory.useLog4J2Logging();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
   LogFactory.useJdkLogging();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
   LogFactory.useNoLogging();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, still got errors:

```
org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogException: Error setting Log implementation.  Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.ibatis.logging.slf4j.Slf4jImpl.<init>(java.lang.String)
        at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.setImplementation(LogFactory.java:113)
        at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.useSlf4jLogging(LogFactory.java:63)
        at com.example.demo.boot3.DemoBoot3Application.<clinit>(DemoBoot3Application.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.ibatis.logging.slf4j.Slf4jImpl.<init>(java.lang.String)
        at java.base@19.0.1/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:3641)
        at java.base@19.0.1/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(DynamicHub.java:2324)
        at org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.setImplementation(LogFactory.java:106)
        ... 2 more
```

**These constructor surely exists, but can't be found**, as following:

```
public Slf4jImpl(String clazz) {
  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);

  if (logger instanceof LocationAwareLogger) {
    try {
      // check for slf4j >= 1.6 method signature
      logger.getClass().getMethod("log", Marker.class, String.class, int.class, String.class, Object[].class, Throwable.class);
      log = new Slf4jLocationAwareLoggerImpl((LocationAwareLogger) logger);
      return;
    } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
      // fail-back to Slf4jLoggerImpl
    }
  }

  // Logger is not LocationAwareLogger or slf4j version < 1.6
  log = new Slf4jLoggerImpl(logger);
}
```

Do anyone know this issue?

Try to init LogFactory manually by using static method, expect vm can find the constructor.
but still get NoSuchMethod error.

After try to use GraalVM agent to generate native image meta, the error is gone.

Then other errors show,

```
Error: Failed to prepare class with hash cb87220bbf3b7662f36953383b7b9076fdf52ee5b3314b7d90ba1bf30ffdc924 from file:/Users/cook/work/pieland/java_demo/demo_boot3/target/classes/META-INF/native-image/agent-extracted-predefined-classes/ for predefinition
```

after i remove predefined-classes-config and org.springframework.boot.loader, the step of compile native image can be done.

But when i try to run the final executable file, it shows Segfault detected:

```
[ [ SubstrateSegfaultHandler caught a segfault in thread 0x00007fb603c0a3c0 ] ]
siginfo: si_signo: 11, si_code: 0, si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Current timestamp: 1670326122279

General purpose register values:
  RAX 0x0000000114aa4568 points into the image heap (read-only huge)
  RBX 0x0000000001311548 is an unknown value
  RCX 0xfffffffffffffff8 is an unknown value
  RDX 0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
  RBP 0x0000000117bf3530 points into an aligned TLAB chunk of thread 0x00007fb603c0a3c0
    is an object of type java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
  RSI 0x0d8e5211a2400d8e is an unknown value
  RDI 0x0d8e521090000d8e is an unknown value
  RSP 0x00007ffee30ce7b0 points into the stack for thread 0x00007fb603c0a3c0
  R8  0x0000000112400000 is the heap base
  R9  0x0000000117bf38e8 points into an aligned TLAB chunk of thread 0x00007fb603c0a3c0
    is an object of type java.util.LinkedHashMap
  R10 0x0000000117bf3518 points into an aligned TLAB chunk of thread 0x00007fb603c0a3c0
    is an object of type jdk.internal.reflect.ConstantPool
  R11 0x000000011317ce30 points into the image heap (read-only references)
    is the hub of org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedJetty
  R12 0x0000000112400000 is the heap base
  R13 0x0000000113678198 points into the image heap (read-only relocatables)
    is the hub of org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes
  R14 0x0000000112400000 is the heap base
  R15 0x00007fb603c0a3c0 is a thread
  EFL 0x0000000000010206 is an unknown value
  RIP 0x000000010e08a586 points into AOT compiled code 
  
Printing Instructions (ip=0x000000010e08a586):
  0x000000010e08a566: 0x5f 0x14 0xff 0x90 0x48 0x8b 0x3c 0x05 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x49 0x8d 0x34 0x3e
  0x000000010e08a576: 0x48 0x85 0xff 0x0f 0x84 0x1e 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x48 0xc7 0xc1 0xf8 0xff 0xff 0xff
  0x000000010e08a586: 0x49 0x23 0x0c 0x3e 0x48 0xbf 0x48 0x15 0x31 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x48 0x3b
  0x000000010e08a596: 0xf9 0x0f 0x85 0x21 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x41 0x83 0x6f 0x10 0x01 0x0f 0x8e 0x08 0x00
```

After i do the final attempt, remove mybitas/jdbc from project, every thing works fine.

And compare graalvm image with boot jar, elapsed time with graal image is 0.073 seconds,
and elapsed time with spring boot jar is 1.987 seconds.

Wow, the speed is so fast, improve up with 90%.

I think that's awesome, but the tech of AOT is not mature, we would always meet some unexpected issue when using graalvm native image.

As now, Mybatis or jdbc is not supported with native image.

Comment: Without taking a closer look at the relevant spring-boot code, my guess is that this could be due to GraalVM's aggressive optimization, removing unused code. GraalVM does not "see" reflective access to classes/methods and thus might remove methods that are accessed through reflection. There is a [tracing agent](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/Agent/) to find reflective calls. Maybe this helps.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for your advice. after i try generate native meta with graalvm agent, there are other errors.

Comment: @PieLand Are you using [mybatis-spring-native](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-native)?

Comment: @ave thanks for the tips. i check the mybatis-spring-native dependencies, it don't support spring boot 3. I am using spring boot 3.

Comment: Hi bro! I am facing the same error, did you solve the problem? If yes, please tell me also, thanks in advance!! Waiting for your reply...